# Links in an XForms expression

Tags: orbeon, xforms

If i have foreign web page addresses like

```
http://example.com/ex1
http://example.com/ex2
http://example.com/ex3
http://example.com/ex4
```

and instance

```
<xforms:instance id="temp">
    <temp>
        <links>
            <item>ex1</item>
            <item>ex2</item>
            <item>ex3</item>
            <item>ex4</item>
        </links>
    </temp>
</xforms:instance>
```

And a cycle

```
<xforms:group ref="instance('temp')/links">
    <xforms:output value="[concat('<a href="http://example.com/',string(item)),'">',string(item),'</a>']">
        <xforms:label>Roll</xforms:label>
    </xforms:output>
</xforms:group>
```

How to put the link in such expression in value attribute in an orbeon xform? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what you want to achieve, but I assume it's to output a series of `<a href="...">`. If so, the following works:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <xh:head>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance id="temp">
                <temp>
                    <links>
                        <item>ex1</item>
                        <item>ex2</item>
                        <item>ex3</item>
                        <item>ex4</item>
                    </links>
                </temp>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <xf:repeat ref="instance('temp')/links/item">
            <xh:a href="http://example.com/{.}">Roll</xh:a>
        </xf:repeat>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```